# Как при вводе той или иной цифры В INPUT вывести определенное значение?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть массив кодов (цифрами). За каждым кодом привязан определенный товар. Как при вводе первой цифры в `input`, вывести его значение в `div`. Например код `25555 первая двойка это холодильник`, `3765756 это телевизор` или аналогия с номерами авто, где регион - это несколько  цифр, а только одна значит регион, но нужно по первой цифре выдавалось информация. Заранее спасибо.

```html
<label for="user_nomber">Номер заказа <br/>
  <input class="formone" id="user_nomber" type="text" placeholder="" />
</label>
<div class="order"></div>
```

[Ссылка на оригинал](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/saneq11/e3nqcwmt/3/)

Comment: Вопрос правил, но что-то сомневаюсь, что уловил суть...  Обращаюсь к автору, если я не правильно понял и суть вопроса передана не правильно, можно исправить, нажав кнопку под вопросом `править`.  Больше всего меня смущает  `аналогия авто`

Comment: @Air [Может быть](https://planetcalc.ru/107/)

Comment: @Даниил, Может быть все при такой формулировке... Почитай оригинал, сам черт ногу сломит...  Товаров может быть куча... Почему первая цифра... Регионов 89, без резерва, почему тоже первая цифра... Скорее, мне кажется, автор хочет сам сделать динамический поиск, но не знал с чего начать и хотел посмотреть, как вообще такое реализовать....   Ну так лучшее решение, на мой взгляд `ajax`, более внятно получиться...  В общем не знаю...

Answer (score 1):

Если по первому символу, можно тип такого:

```js
$("#user_nomber").on("input", function(){
  var val = $(this).val().substr(0,1);
  switch (val) {
  case "1":
   $(".order").text("Холодильник");
    break;
  case "2":
   $(".order").text("Телевизор");
    break;
  case "3":
   $(".order").text("Полка");
    break;
  default:
   $(".order").text("Нет такого");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="user_nomber">Номер заказа<br>

  <input class="formone" id="user_nomber" type="text" placeholder="" />
</label><br>

<div class="order"></div>
```

Если только по одной цифре, можно вот так:

```js
$("#user_nomber").on("input", function(){
  var val = $(this).val();  
  switch (val) {
  case "1":
   $(".order").text("Холодильник");
    break;
  case "2":
   $(".order").text("Телевизор");
    break;
  case "3":
   $(".order").text("Полка");
    break;
  default:
   $(".order").text("Нет такого");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="user_nomber">Номер заказа<br>

  <input class="formone" id="user_nomber" type="text" placeholder="" />
</label><br>

<div class="order"></div>
```